Failed to load javascript module. Server responded with MIME of text/html
I tried deploying my angular 17 project from my local machine to azure. For creating a dist folder I have created a web config and referenced it by adding it in angular json file under "build". The dist folder got created upon running "ng build" I hava attached the web config file as well as the index.html generated in dist folder.Am facing this error while trying to deploy the app to azure app service.

the above attached image contains the error I am facing.  Error : "Failed to load module script : Expected javascript module but server returned MIME type of text/html.
**Web.config**

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
    </staticContent>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="(REQUEST_FILENAME)" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add
              input="(REQUEST_FILENAME)"
              matchType="IsDirectory"
              negate="true"
            />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Contains the error description

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-critters-container>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>SmartSA2App</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="styles-6DJROMVX.css"
      media="print"
      onload="this.media='all'"
    />
    <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-6DJROMVX.css" /></noscript>
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script src="polyfills-FFHMD2TL.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="main-KHKTSFNE.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>


The first thing you should do to debug this is to look at the URL that is being requested and find out if it is a JavaScript file that the server is claiming is HTML or if it is an HTML document. It is almost certainly the latter and reading the HTML document will probably give you a clue about what the problem is (such as if it is a 404 Not Found error or if it is a login page).
